# Text to image in java

Tags: java, image, swing, text

I am trying to convert a line of text in a .txt file to a .jpeg image in java. I wrote the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProjTry extends JFrame
{
    static BufferedImage img;
    static Graphics g;
    static String s;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);
    }

    /* public*/ ProjTry(String fname) //throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
                //EDIT
                while ((s=br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }

            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        finally
            {
                try
                    {
                        if (br != null)br.close();
                    }
                catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        ProjTry tx=new ProjTry("E:\\Java\\file.txt");
        JFrame j=new JFrame("Demo");
        g=img.getGraphics();
        g.drawString(s,0,0);
        try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("E:\\Java\\t2img.jpg");
                ImageIO.writeImage(img,"jpg",fos);
                fos.close();
            }
        catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Here my file is named "file.txt". However the compiler continually shows 2 errors . What am I to do?

Errors::

line 17: cannot find symbol

```
     super(.)paintComponent(g);
```

Symbol: method paintComponent(Graphics)

line 79: cannot find symbol

```
     ImageIO(.)writeImage(img,"jpg",fos);
```

Symbol: method writeImage(BufferedImage,String,FileOutputStream)

location: class ImageIO

Comment: Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: If this is actually your entire class, you're missing a `}` at the end.

Comment: @Zircon :Sorry about that, but after correction , it shows 14 errors that I am not being able to understand. Please help

Comment: typos, capitalization,.....

Comment: Well, off the bat it would be `JFrame` not "Jframe".

Comment: e.g., Jframe? you can't be careless when coding.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Changes made . Sorry for the typos

Comment: @KevinO :Please help. Typos corrected..

Comment: Show any and all error messages. But before doing so, read them critically as they will usually tell you exactly what's wrong, and pretty clearly too.

Comment: Closer but still not there. You mis-copied the code and are missing important pieces. Re-look at the links.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I copied only the reading a text fro a .txt file part from [link](www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example) . I have worked with the fileoutputstream part and it had worked. I dont know why it is not working now..

Comment: @Qwerty: this, `while ((s br.readLine()) != null)` won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages are telling you exactly what's wrong -- believe them and check them out, and you'll be able to fix these and similar problems on your own.

```
public class ProjTry extends JFrame
{
    static BufferedImage img;
    static Graphics g;
    static String s;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);
    }
```

> The method paintComponent(Graphics) is undefined for the type JFrame

The [JFrame API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) will confirm that this is true, and you should look up the API when you see this and similar errors. It looks like you've copied painting code for a JPanel and plopped it into a JFrame, and you shouldn't do this. Paint inside of a class that extends JPanel, just like it is done in the code that you borrowed this from, and then place that JPanel into a JFrame.

Also always preface your override methods -- methods that you *think* override a parent class method -- with the `@Override` annotation. If you did this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   // etc...
```

the compiler would warn you that you're not actually overriding a super method.

Site note: the paintComponent method should be `protected` not `public`

---

```
ImageIO.writeImage(img,"jpg",fos);
```

> The method writeImage(BufferedImage, String, FileOutputStream) is undefined for the type ImageIO

Again the [ImageIO API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) will confirm that this is true, and in fact **there is no writeImage method for this class**. Use the `ImageIO.write(...)` method instead, *just as the API will show you. Or more generally: Only use the methods that the API says are available to use.

For example -- without the write image file:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;    
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawOnImg extends JPanel {
    public static final String IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/"
            + "wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Thomas_Hicks_-_Leopold_Grozelier_-_"
            + "Presidential_Candidate_Abraham_Lincoln_1860.jpg/"
            + "456px-Thomas_Hicks_-_Leopold_Grozelier_-_Presidential_Candidate_"
            + "Abraham_Lincoln_1860.jpg";
    public static final String TXT_PATH = "http://history.eserver.org/"
            + "gettysburg-address.txt";
    public static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private BufferedImage backgroundImg = null;

    public DrawOnImg(BufferedImage img, String text) {
        backgroundImg = img;

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(text);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(textArea);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (backgroundImg != null) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || backgroundImg == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = backgroundImg.getWidth();
        int h = backgroundImg.getHeight();
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui(BufferedImage img, String text) {
        DrawOnImg mainPanel = new DrawOnImg(img, text);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawOnImg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            URL txtUrl = new URL(TXT_PATH);
            scanner = new Scanner(txtUrl.openStream());
            final String text = readText(scanner);

            URL imgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
            final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui(img, text));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        } finally {
            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
            }
        }

    }

    private static String readText(Scanner scanner) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean save = false;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (line.startsWith("Four score")) {
                save = true;
            } 
            if (line.startsWith("-----")) {
                save = false;
            }
            if (save && !line.isEmpty()) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(NEW_LINE);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Comment: I followed your instructions, and it compiles perfectly. However, there is one major problem: The text in my text file is being printed an infinite number if times.. Can you please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: @Qwerty: that's not how you read text from a file using a BufferedReader. Look at the while loop -- do you ever read in text from within the loop? Will `s` ever change? Will it ever become null? Answers: no, no, and no. Search on how to read text from a text file using a BufferedReader and follow the example found.

Comment: @Qwerty: [Google search, first hit](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+reading+text+file+bufferedreader+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: I did so. Still a problem lies. Can you tell me why no output image is being produced? I mean I thought I should get a jpg file with the name "t2img" in the desired location

Comment: Also during runtime, it is giving a null pointer exception in line 58. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Qwerty: What line is line 58? Something on that line is null, and you need to fix it.

Comment: @Qwerty: also these are new problems and so may need new questions, if complex.